# Minimal number of cuts of rectangle in squares

Tags: c, dynamic-programming

The task is to find minimal number of cuts of rectangle in squares. I wrote a recursive function to do so, but the point is to write it using dynamic programming. I wrote the matrix on the paper but still find it difficult to write a code.. Here a and b are dimensions of rectangle:

```
int minimalNumOfCuts(int a, int b)
{
    if (a==b) return 0;
    int result;
    if (a<b)
        result = 1+minimalNumOfCuts(b-a,a);//found a square with side a, so I add 1 and recurs on 
    else result = 1+minimalNumOfCuts(a-b,b);//found a square with side b
    return result;
}
```

For example, for rectangle 3x5 the function should return 3, which is the number of minimal cuts required to get one square with side 3, one with side 2, and two squares with sides of 1.

Here is how I think (if I use dynamic programming) the matrix should look, when I solve the subproblems (smaller rectangles). The column and row with zeroes is not needed.

[image]

Comment: Please elaborate on the problem, and use meaning variable names so we can understand your code

Comment: and what is 'dynamic programming'

Comment: @pm100, judging by the description the tag `Dynamic programming is an algorithmic technique for efficiently solving problems with a recursive structure containing many overlapping subproblems` the OP might want a recursive method, though it's not quite clear.

Comment: that tag text reads like bs to me, OP code is recursive

Comment: @pm100, lol, since you didn't tagged me I almost missed your great comment, that would be a shame. I have to agree with you assessment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You go through the rectangle with an euclidean algorithm, which is kind of what you are trying there, and count the cuts, there are some possiblilities for a recursive function that could achieve this, here is a possible implementation passing a counter pointer as argument of the function to be changed in the inner recursions:

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/Hyd3i60sL)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void minimalNumOfCuts(int side1, int side2, int *count);

int main() {
    int side1 = 3, side2 = 5, count = 0;

    minimalNumOfCuts(side1, side2, &count);
    printf("Height %d Length %d - %d cuts\n", side1, side2, count);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void minimalNumOfCuts(int side1, int side2, int *count) {

    if (side1 == side2) {
        return;
    }

    if (side1 > side2) {
        side1 -= side2;
    }
    else {
        side2 -= side1;
    }
    (*count)++;
    minimalNumOfCuts(side1, side2, count); //recursive call
}
```

Output:

```
Height 3 Length 5 - 3 cuts
```

**EDIT:**

For your table just cycle through the values:

This sample counts the cuts from a rectangle with height ranging from 1 to 5 and length ranging from 1 to 4 using the same recursive function.

[Live demo](https://onlinegdb.com/SJFK9T0o8)

```
#define MAX_HEIGHT 5
#define MAX_LENGHT 4

int main() {

    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < MAX_HEIGHT + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < MAX_LENGHT + 1; j++) {   
            minimalNumOfCuts(i, j, &count);
            printf("Height %d Length %d - %d cuts\n", i, j, count);
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
Height 1 Length 1 - 0 cuts
Height 1 Length 2 - 1 cuts
Height 1 Length 3 - 2 cuts
Height 1 Length 4 - 3 cuts
Height 2 Length 1 - 1 cuts
Height 2 Length 2 - 0 cuts
Height 2 Length 3 - 2 cuts
Height 2 Length 4 - 1 cuts
Height 3 Length 1 - 2 cuts
Height 3 Length 2 - 2 cuts
Height 3 Length 3 - 0 cuts
Height 3 Length 4 - 3 cuts
Height 4 Length 1 - 3 cuts
Height 4 Length 2 - 1 cuts
Height 4 Length 3 - 3 cuts
Height 4 Length 4 - 0 cuts
Height 5 Length 1 - 4 cuts
Height 5 Length 2 - 3 cuts
Height 5 Length 3 - 3 cuts
Height 5 Length 4 - 4 cuts
```

[Here is a nice graphic demonstration](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/TheEuclideanAlgorithm/) where you can check the results.

Note that there are some imprecisions in your table, for instance, a rectangle with sides 3 and 4 will need only 3 cuts.